# Compile errors while using room persistence library in a kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have been facing a problem for days now.
I'm developing an app using Kotlin and room persistence library. My database consists of 4 entities. The problem is whenever I add 
`kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"` regardless of the room version I get the following compile errors and warnings:

```js
C:\Users\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jre7\1.2.0\ec8b969e26fbcf2265a4d1a1539c4d1d4c5af380\kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.2.0.jar: kotlin-stdlib-jre7 is deprecated. Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 instead 

C:\Users\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jre8\1.2.0\505f55b9619bbc5f5e26c77427dd24a6a441eef1\kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.jar: kotlin-stdlib-jre8 is deprecated. Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 instead 

C:\Users\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jre7\1.2.0\ec8b969e26fbcf2265a4d1a1539c4d1d4c5af380\kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.2.0.jar: kotlin-stdlib-jre7 is deprecated. Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 instead 

C:\Users\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jre8\1.2.0\505f55b9619bbc5f5e26c77427dd24a6a441eef1\kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.jar: kotlin-stdlib-jre8 is deprecated. Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 instead 

C:/Users/Desktop/Meals_App 
app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/appDatabase/appDao.java 
error: cannot find symbol
    public abstract java.util.List<appDatabase.recipesEntity> getAll();
                                              ^
  symbol:   class recipesEntity
  location: class appDatabase 

error: cannot find symbol
    appDatabase.recipesEntity recipes);
               ^
  symbol:   class recipesEntity
  location: class appDatabase 

error: cannot find symbol
    appDatabase.chefEntity chefs);
               ^
  symbol:   class chefEntity
  location: class appDatabase 

error: cannot find symbol
    appDatabase.recipesEntity recipes);
               ^
  symbol:   class recipesEntity
  location: class appDatabase 
app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/appDatabase/appDatabase.java 

error: cannot find symbol
    public abstract appDatabase.appDao appDao();
                               ^
  symbol:   class appDao
  location: class appDatabase 

error: cannot find symbol
@android.arch.persistence.room.Database(entities = {appDatabase.recipesEntity.class, appDatabase.chefEntity.class, appDatabase.stepsEntity.class, appDatabase.ingredientEntity.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
                                                                                                ^
  symbol:   class chefEntity
  location: class appDatabase 

error: cannot find symbol
@android.arch.persistence.room.Database(entities = {appDatabase.recipesEntity.class, appDatabase.chefEntity.class, appDatabase.stepsEntity.class, appDatabase.ingredientEntity.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
                                                                                                                                                             ^
  symbol:   class ingredientEntity
  location: class appDatabase 

error: android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public abstract class appDatabase extends android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase {
                ^ 
app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/appDatabase/ingredientEntity.java 

error: cannot find symbol
    public final appDatabase.ingredientEntity copy(int ingID, int recipeID, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                            ^
  symbol:   class ingredientEntity
  location: class appDatabase 
app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/appDatabase/stepsEntity.java 

error: cannot find symbol
    public final appDatabase.stepsEntity copy(int stepID, int recipeID, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                            ^
  symbol:   class stepsEntity
  location: class appDatabase 
app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/appDatabase/recipesEntity.java 

error: cannot find symbol
@android.arch.persistence.room.Entity(tableName = "recipesEntity", foreignKeys = {@android.arch.persistence.room.ForeignKey(entity = appDatabase.chefEntity.class, childColumns = {"chefID"}, onDelete = 5, parentColumns = {"chefID"})})
                                                                                                                                                ^
  symbol:   class chefEntity
  location: class appDatabase 

error: android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public final class recipesEntity {
             ^ 
app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/appDatabase/chefEntity.java 

error: android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public final class chefEntity {
             ^
```

**Here are my database classes:** 
**ChefEntity.kt**

```js
@Entity(tableName = "chefEntity", indices = [(Index(value = ("username"), unique = true))])

data class chefEntity(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "chef_id")
        var chefID: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "firstname")
        var firstname: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "lastname")
        var lastname: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "username")
        var username: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "password")
        var password: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "address")
        var address: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "mobile")
        var mobile: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "bg_color")
        var bg_color: Int
 )
```

**recipesEntity.kt**

```js
@Entity(tableName = "recipesEntity",
        foreignKeys = [(ForeignKey(entity = chefEntity::class,
                parentColumns = [("chefID")],
                childColumns = [("chefID")],
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))])

data class recipesEntity(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "recipeID")
        val recipeID: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "chef_id")
        val chefID: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
        val name: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "prep_time")
        val pTime: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "image_name")
        val imageName: String
)
```

**ingredientEntity.kt**

```js
@Entity(tableName = "ingredientEntity",
        foreignKeys = [(ForeignKey(entity = recipesEntity::class,
                parentColumns = [("recipeID")],
                childColumns = [("recipeID")],
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))])

data class ingredientEntity(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "ingredient_id")
        var ingID: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "recipeID")
        var recipeID: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "ingredient_name")
        var name: String
)
```

**stepsEntity.kt**

```js
@Entity(tableName = "stepsEntity",
        foreignKeys = [(ForeignKey(entity = recipesEntity::class,
                parentColumns = [("recipeID")],
                childColumns = [("recipeID")],
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))])

data class stepsEntity(
        @PrimaryKey()
        @ColumnInfo(name = "step_id")
        val stepID: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "recipeID")
        val recipeID: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "desciption")
        val desciption: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "order")
        val order: Int
)
```

**appDatabase**

```js
@Database(entities = [(recipesEntity::class), (chefEntity::class), (stepsEntity::class), (ingredientEntity::class)],
        version = 1, exportSchema = false)

abstract class appDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun appDao(): appDao
}
```

**appDao**

```js
@Dao
interface appDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from recipesEntity")
    fun getAll(): List<recipesEntity>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(recipes: recipesEntity)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(chefs: chefEntity)

    @Update
    fun update(recipes: recipesEntity)

    @Query("DELETE from recipesEntity")
    fun deleteAll()

}
```

**Module:app**

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sawsan.mealsapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.41"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.pes.materialcolorpicker:library:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'

    //Room

    def room_version = "1.1.1-rc1" // or, for latest rc, use "1.1.1-rc1"

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"

    // Extensions = ViewModel + LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    //RxJava support for Room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"

    //RxJava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
}
```

I hope someone can help me solve this problem since I couldn't find any similar case online.
Sorry for taking so long, and thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm still checking your problem but I can't help but notice that chefEntity class is annotated with recipesEntity

Comment: I noticed that, and fixed it. Still getting same errors though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, make sure that your files extension is correct, for example I had a file which was called `AccreditationLogo` not `AccreditationLogo.kt`. This seemed to mess around with the compiler in an odd way.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find the problem so I took an old project that compiles room correctly and moved everything to it. And about to finish the whole project in few days. Thank you for your information dear :)

Comment: Ah, fair enough. This sort of thing recently caught me out, it took a few hours to figure such a simple thing out. But hopefully this will help someone else out. As it doesn't seem that obvious that this could be the issue.